# Лишнее слово

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Опираясь на историю происхождения слов, определите, какое является «лишним» в каждом ряду и почему:

1. Сумерки, супруг, суд, судьба, сутки.
2. Байка, басня, бас, краснобай, прибаутка, обаяние.
3. Старый, бурый, мудрый, добрый, пестрый, шустрый.

Comment: А причем тут однокоренные слова? По крайней мере в 3 пункте?

Comment: А мы вообще-то делаем олимпиадные задания?  
Пусть даже чувашского университета?!  

http://www.chuvsu.ru/~fil_fak/images/stories/viktorina/rus_jaz_1_tur_10_2012.doc

Answer (score 1):

Даю версию, за которую бы сам не поручился, но задание - изначально "на засыпку", гадать, что там автору в голову пришло...

~1. суд -  "су" здесь корневое, в остальных случаях - приставка со значением "совместный, общий". (В отношении судьбы - спорно, но вроде бы тоже приставка).
~2. бас - остальные слова - от праславянского корня "ба(й)" (баять) - говорить.
~3. добрый - восходит к корню "доб", откуда доблесть и проч., р (историческое "Ър") - древний суффикс. В Остальных словах р - корневое.  "Пестрый"  в принципе тоже восходит к пес, писать, но это гораздо более древнее образование.

Это навскидку, в олимпиадном темпе.
Ногами только не бейте, не вопрос, а гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Первые два мне показалось так же, но вроде судьба происходит от "суд"

Comment: >вроде судьба происходит от "суд"  
   
Есть достоверный источник? Вроде бы да, но есть фонетические сомнения. 
Удивительно, но Фасмер про судьбу ничего не пишет.

Comment: Не знаю, сведения из интернета, но не из солидных словарей. Впрочем, дело даже не в этом. Не могу представить, какой корень слова *судьба*, если *су* - приставка? Дыба, что ли :-)

Comment: "Де/дь". От деять. -б(а)  - обычный суффикс.
Но это версия. 
Впрочем, кто ентих чувашей поймет???

Comment: Судьба образована от 'суд' суффиксальным способом, поэтому выпадает из общего ряда (также от суда, судить происходит суженый). Остальные слова образованы с помощью приставки су-, в том числе и **судъ**. Суд - совместное постановление, которое обсуждали все вместе. Единоличного суда не было.

Comment: Первоначально "судъ"(через юс)сложилось из предлога "су " и индоевропейского существительного *"dhos" (из"dhe", которое мы видим в словах "дело", "деть"). Значение было -"со-деянное".(Л.Успенский)Судьба -производное от *sǫdъ «суд» с помощью суффикса -ьb-a(Черных)
Получается, что везде приставка су-, только в сумерках она означает неполноту. Но там ведь в вопросе "с точки зрения происхождения", а происхождением отличается только старославянизм супруг.

Comment: В 3. слово шустрый - по происхождению - от арго:ШУСТРЫЙ - Из неустановленной формы. Впервые отмечается в середине XIX в. По одной версии — слово арготического происхождения; представляет собой перелицовку общерусского слова острый (или, возможно, быстрый) с помощью арготической приставки шу-, применявшейся для искажения слов в арго. Отмечены аналогичные формы: шутро (утро), шурман (карман), шусто (место),шиблоко (яблоко), шилго (долго). По другой версии — связано с шут. Может, его имели в виду? Или тюркизм бурый

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, так:1.    супруг( старославянизм), 
2.   бас –(другое значение корня), 
3.   бурый- заимствование